# How to Reply to Inbound SMS with MMS in WordPress PHP Twilio

Tags: php, wordpress, twilio, mms

Using WordPress PHP and Twilio, how can I reply to an inbound SMS with a message that contains media. Specifically I want to reply to inbound messages with an image. I'm having trouble finding a way to add media to the response. How do I add an image to the format used below?

```
function trigger_receive_sms($request) {
  echo header('content-type: text/xml');
  echo ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');
  echo ('<Response>');
  echo ('<Message>Hello there, did you get the image?</Message>');
  echo ('</Response>');
}
```

Used this guide for overall foundation: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/09/receive-sms-wordpress-php-plugin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To respond with media you need to [nest `<Media>` and `<Body>` elements in your `<Message>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml/message#nouns). `<Media>` should have a URL to the media you want to reply with.

```php
function trigger_receive_sms($request) {
  echo header('content-type: text/xml');
  echo ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');
  echo ('<Response>');
  echo ('  <Message>');
  echo ('    <Body>Hello there, did you get the image?</Body>');
  echo ('    <Media>https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png</Media>');
  echo ('  </Message>');
  echo ('</Response>');
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: yes this did the trick! Thank you very much. I was trying to throw the <media> tags in there in a variety of wrong ways. Looks like I didn't search the twilio documentation enough. Thanks again for pointing this out.